# How to Align ASP Button Adjacent to Top of Label

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a label that has several lines and then a button next to it. Right now the button always aligns next to the bottom of the label, but I want it at the top.

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblServerGroupAddedShort" runat="server"/>
 <asp:Button ID="btnServerGroupShowAll" runat="server" Text="Show All" Height="20px" Width="70px" Font-Size="Smaller" />
```

Comment: Add `vertical-align:top` to the css for the button.

Comment: I tried adding that in the inline CSS, but it did not work.

Comment: Can you show more code then - create a [mcve] from the generated HTML and CSS.